# open html/css file with MS Word - element table - apply no text wrapping

Tags: css, html-table, ms-word, css-position, nowrap

I am looking to open an `HTML/CSS` file with *MS Word*. I have a table in the file and would like to set the table properties, *text wrapping to NONE* using CSS. I understand Word should be able to interpret the HTML/CSS.

I cannot find any CSS to apply `NO text wrapping` to an *entire table*. Can anyone help?

Comment: You are probably looking for the css `white-space: nowrap;` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing your styles separately, you can define your css as such:

```
table th,
table td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

That is going to make ALL table header and regular cells not wrap, so be aware of that. If you are trying to make this change and you need to target a cell directly, you would have to make the above CSS more specific by adding class names to the cells you want to target. Or add the CSS inline to the cell: `<td style="white-space:nowrap"></td>`